# Docker container crontab not running

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile image based on ubuntu. Iam trying to make a bash script run each day but the cron never runs. When the container is running, i check if cron is running and it is. the bash script works perfectly and the crontab command is well copied inside the container. i can't seem to find where the problem is coming from.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM snipe/snipe-it:latest

ENV TZ=America/Toronto

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install awscli -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get install cron -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/backups_scripts /var/www/html/config/scripts

COPY config/crontab.txt /var/www/html/backups_scripts
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /var/www/html/backups_scripts/crontab.txt

COPY config/scripts/backups.sh /var/www/html/config/scripts

CMD ["cron","-f"]
```

The last command CMD doesn't work. And as soon as i remove the cmd command i get this message when i check the cron task inside the container:

```
root@fcfb6052274a:/var/www/html# /etc/init.d/cron status
 * cron is not running
```

Even if i start the cron process before the crontab, the crontab is still not launched

How can i tackle this problem ??? Thank you

Comment: Docker images usually don't have any services running, though this also depends on the specific image. Have you checked whether it's even supposed to be there?

Comment: @tripleee it is an ubuntu based image + i do install cron inside the dockerfile. And on top of that even when i exec the container, start the cron process manually, it still never run the crontab.

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` doesn't demonstrate this; could you please [edit] your question to clarify where and how this happens?

Comment: @tripleee snipe/snipe-it:latest is an ubuntu based image and the cron is installed with " && apt-get install cron -y \ ".  the crontab is copied but never runs

Comment: @tripleee. I Had to make another service to make it work alongside the original service. And on top of that i found the env vars were not injected during the processing of the bash script, why ? Because a sh script which runs due to a cron, we actually need to source+exports the vars. A cronjob opens a new shell that is the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

You are running `crontab` in a `RUN` statement. But that only runs during image creation, not when you actually use the resulting image.

Comment: this image is used by a docker stack, so how can i tackle this issue within the dockerfile or the compose file ? thanks

Comment: The *default* startup command in `CMD` should probably be a script which starts up any and all services and takes care to keep them running. Maybe look for ways to run a service manager in Docker so you don't have to reinvent clumsy hacks with endless loops. But realize that conventional service managers like `runit` are often a bad fit for Docker.